# Grouping and pushing data from all objects into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to achieve the following:
Say you have an array of objects, as so:

```
[{familyName: "Winston", data: [{},{}]}, {familyName: "Winston", data: [{},{}]}, {familyName: "Winston", data: [{},{}]}, {familyName: "Levi", data: [{},{}]}, {familyName: "Levi", data: [{},{}]}]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is grouping each family name to a new object that will contain all the data of the same family name. For example:

```
[ { familyName: "Winston", data:[{},{},{},{},{},{}] }, { familyName: "Levi", data: [{},{},{},{}] } //new array will contain the combined data objects
```

So, in the end, I'll have an array with one object for each unique property + the sum of all the data objects for that particular property.
I managed to achieve this by creating a "template array" and then pushing it as so:

```
for (let name of array) {
            for (let property of templateArray) {
                if (name.familyName === property.familyName) {
                    property.data.push(name)
                }
            }
        }
```

I was hoping to find a more elegant and efficient solution, maybe even without creating the template array beforehand. Is there?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object with `familyName` as keys and collect the object. Finally take only the values from the object as result.

```js
const
    data = [{ familyName: "Winston", data: [{}, {}] }, { familyName: "Winston", data: [{}, {}] }, { familyName: "Winston", data: [{}, {}] }, { familyName: "Levi", data: [{}, {}] }, { familyName: "Levi", data: [{}, {}] }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, o) => {
        (r[o.familyName] ??=  { ...o, data: [] }).data.push(...o.data);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks!
May I ask what's this syntax? "??="
My ide throws me an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'

Comment: it is a [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), you could replace `(r[o.familyName] ??=  { ...o, data: [] })` with a [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR): `(r[o.familyName] = r[o.familyName] || { ...o, data: [] })`